# Is it possible to flag certain files to never cause merge conflicts in Git?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-merge-conflict

Is it possible, upon merges and rebases, to specify that certain files should automatically resolve in "use ours" (or some other policy) where a merge conflict would normally happen?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [git attributes](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes)
You can create a .gitattribute file in the root folder of your repo.
If for example you have a file named database.xml that evolves in two different branches and you want to merge in your other branch without messing up the database file, you could set the git attribute as follows

```
database.xml merge=ours
```